# Python Pseudocode help needed . just copy and paste the link into google

Tags: python, pseudocode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRsOq.png)

hi there, i am struggling with this question and i have missed lessons because of covid therefore i am behind, it would be really appreciated if someone could answer this question in python code. Copy and paste the link onto a new tab

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to Ask Homework Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: There's no way the question could get a legitimate upvote; it flies in the face of every SO question-asking guideline. OP: it's not that people don't want to, it won't, help--it's that it completely ignores everything in the links provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
answer <- 0 // Making "answer" 0
column <- 8 // Making "column" 8

WHILE column < 1: // While "column" is less than 1:
    OUTPUT "Enter bit value" // Prints the text
    bit <- USERINPUT // The user's reply is saved to "bit"
    answer <- answer + (column * bit) // Sum
    column <- column / 2 // Making "column" half its' value

// While "column" is NOT less than 1:

OUTPUT "Decimal Value is: ", answer // Prints the text followed by the value of "answer"
```

Comment: YMMV but I'm not super-comfortable with SO as a HaaS site.

Comment: @DaveNewton Isn't this okay, as it is answering ***one question***, so not really teaching, if you understand what I mean.

Comment: SO isn't Homework as a Service.